# Visualize Texture3D with opacity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I want to visualize a Texture3D with see though opacity sections.

My Texture3D data works and can visualize using this shader
https://github.com/nakamura001/Unity-3DVolumeTexture/blob/master/Assets/Sample3DTexture.shader

But would like to use opacity levels. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Update 1-1-2018 This project comes close https://github.com/gillesferrand/Unity-RayTracing

Comment: `*looks at shader code*` Mmm...nope, beats me. I've worked with shaders a lot and that one's small. But I *still* have no idea how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to test, I'm pretty sure creating a struct and passing it to a float4 should do the trick:

```
struct ps_color {
        float4 col : COLOR;
};

ps_color maincol (ps_input i)
    {
        ps_color c;
        c.col = tex3D (_Volume, i.uv);
        return c;
    }

float4 frag (ps_color j) : COLOR
    {
        return float4(j.col.rgb, 1.0); //1.0, in this case, is your alpha.
    }
```